# get rid of negative values in the prediction interval of fable's forecast using an ETS model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, fable-r

I have used fable's forecast with an ETS model like so:

```
stl.fc <- train |>
  model(stlf = decomposition_model(
    STL(value), # decomposition to use (STL)
    ETS(season_adjust),
    SNAIVE(season_year) # it's the default but we make it explicit
  )) |>
  forecast(h = TIME_HORIZON)
```

My data consists of number of asylum applications and must be positive or zero.
When I try to plot the result of the forecast with autoplot, the prediction interval is also shown (which is good), but its values can be also negative (which is not good).

```
stl.fc |>
  autoplot(data.tsbl)
```

[image]

I am trying to get rid of those negative values, but it seems tricky since the object containing such values is of class `"distribution" "vctrs_vctr"   "list"` and I have no idea how to do this.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks like (the column I am referring to is called `value`).

[image]

Each element in the `value` column looks like a list of two entries, `mu` and `sigma`, which I can see with (e.g.) `unlist(stl.fc$value[1])`

```
      mu    sigma 
8087.440 3308.573
```

From here I am a bit stuck as to how to remove those negative numbers.

I am inspecting this ["Ensuring forecasts stay within limits"](https://otexts.com/fpp3/limits.html) page of the "Forecasting: Principles and Practive" book but I seem to fail to understand how to achieve what I want.

Alternatively I think I would also live if I can just get rid of the negative Y-values in the plot (i.e. hiding those negative values), but this feels more like cheating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED WITH A MUCH SIMPLER APPROACH**

Thanks to [Mitchell O'Hara-Wild's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11122210/mitchell-ohara-wild), here is a simple solution:

```
stl.fc <- train |>
  model(stlf = decomposition_model(
    STL(value), # decomposition to use (STL)
    ETS(season_adjust),
    SNAIVE(season_year) # it's the default but we make it explicit
  )) |>
  forecast(h = TIME_HORIZON) |>
  mutate(value = distributional::dist_truncated(value, 0)) # SOLUTION ;)
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I finally came up with a solution that instead of letting the tool calculate the prediction interval automatically, generates 1000 simulated paths (inspired by [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/combinations.html)), and before aggregating these by date, change the negative values to zero.

Below the script and the new plot:

```
# create the model
stl.mod <- train |>
  model(stlf = decomposition_model(
    STL(value), # decomposition to use (STL)
    ETS(season_adjust),
    SNAIVE(season_year) # it's the default but we make it explicit
  ))

# generate simulated paths and change negative values to zero before aggregating
# https://otexts.com/fpp3/combinations.html
stl.fc <- stl.mod |>
  # Generate 1000 future sample paths
  generate(h = TIME_HORIZON, times = 1000) |>
  mutate(.sim = if_else(.sim < 0, 0, .sim)) |>
  # Compute forecast distributions from future sample paths
  as_tibble() |>
  group_by(date, .model) |>
  summarise(
    dist = distributional::dist_sample(list(.sim))
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  # Create fable object
  as_fable(index = date, key = .model,
           distribution = dist, response = "value")

stl.fc |>
  autoplot(data.tsbl)
```

[image]

Comment: To achieve the same thing without simulating future paths you can truncate the forecast distribution with `distributional::dist_truncated(value, 0)`. Alternatively you can log transform the data to produce non-negative forecasts.

Comment: Seems much simpler, I will give it a try tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: For some reasons, `distributional::dist_truncated(value, 0)` does not seem to work. `Error: object 'value' not found`, although the column is clearly there. I tried `stl.mod |> forecast(h = TIME_HORIZON) |>  distributional::dist_truncated(lower = 0, upper = value)`.

Comment: You need to mutate() the distribution. e.g. `forecast() |> mutate(value = dist_truncated(value, 0))`.